# Disk size shown to be less than 100Mb for a 1To drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, debian, mount, disk-space

Good evening,

I am trying to setup a backup disk on my Debian server, but it is recognized as having only 96Mb of space, when it's a 2To hard disk. I let you see it by yourself :

[[image: 1]]

This means the drive is unusable, even though it is recognized by all other utilities as having 2To of free space and enough inodes :

[[image: 1]]
[[image: 2]]
[[image: 4]]

*What can be wrong ?*

Thanks for your help

Comment: The only suspicious thing could be the output of blkid :

*/dev/sda1: LABEL="RM-CM-)servM-CM-) au systM-CM-(me" UUID="322E1C9D2E1C5C63" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0ea671a2-01"*

Comment: Here is my entry in /etc/fstab : *UUID=322E1C9D2E1C5C63                     /backup         ntfs    defaults        1       2*

Comment: The `df` utility shows the size of *filesystems* on the disk, whereas `fdisk` shows the size of *partitions.* Filesystems are (usually) stored inside partitions, but for any of several reasons, the two data structures' sizes need not match. I recommend you unmount `/dev/sda1`, create a fresh filesystem on it that fills the partition, and then re-mount `/dev/sda1`. Also, your previous comment suggests that the filesystem is NTFS, but the partition is marked as type 0x83, which is for Linux-native filesystems, like ext2/3/4fs. You should probably use a Linux filesystem to back up Linux data.

Comment: Could you point me to a full tutorial on how to do this ? I already tried doing this with fdisk but it looks like it failed, i deleted the partition and created a new one taking up the whole space and wrote it :/

Comment: You wouldn't use `fdisk` for this; it manipulates partitions, as I said. You'd use `mkfs` (in conjunction with `umount` and `mount`), as in `umount /dev/sda1 && mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1 && mount /dev/sda1 /backup`. Alternatively, if you prefer a GUI tool, you can use GParted, which manipulates both partitions and filesystems. Note that creating a new filesystem (often called "formatting a partition" or something similar) deletes all existing data on the partition, so don't do this if the partition holds anything important!